# git cherry-pick -x default

Tags: git, config, cherry-pick

In the [man page for](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt--x) `git cherry-pick`:

```
...

-x
    When recording the commit, append a line that says "(cherry picked
    from commit …)" to the original commit message in order to indicate
    which commit this change was cherry-picked from. ...

-r
    It used to be that the command defaulted to do -x described above,
    and -r was to disable it. Now the default is not to do -x so this
    option is a no-op.

...
```

Is there a config setting to locally set the default back to `-x`, and allow `-r` to disable it?  I couldn't find one, but I may have missed it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Short of making an alias for `git cherry-pick -x`, no, this is not possible.

(Fun fact: The default was changed in commit [abd6970](https://github.com/git/git/commit/abd6970acad5d758f48c13f7420367ae8216038e).)

Comment: The detail about private commits was my "ah-ha!" moment.  Thanks for the link to the commit that explained it.

Answer (score 5):

add this alias to your ~/.gitconfig by running:

```
git config --global --replace-all alias.pick "cherry-pick -x"
```

You can then simply run:

```
git pick abc123
```

You may replace the choice of "pick" to whatever word makes sense to you.